# Changing Woocommerce mini-cart behaviour

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, minicart

I am trying to change woo-commerce default mini-cart behavior to be a navigation button only (with the number for quantity number at the right corner of the icon) and I am currently modifying it at child theme. At the moment, I hide the mini-cart content (the container that holds the ordered items) by using `display: none;` in my custom CSS.

The question is how can I change my icon to direct the user to my "cart" page?

Answer (score 0):

that totally depends on how you are editing your mini cart.

You can actually create your own html mark up.

`childtheme/woocommerce/cart/mini-cart.php.`  [with this content](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/cart/mini-cart.php).
That way, you have more control than just css.

Comment: Hi @Reigel, thanks for your reply. Yes, I did like what you exactly mentioned there. Currently, I am trying to disable the mini-cart behavior (showing all the chosen products) and make it as navigation for users to go to the "Cart page".

For the CSS side, I use it for hiding the mini-cart content container. Do you want me to send you a screenshot so that for clarification?

Comment: @Leongpin please add the image on the original post